# VisJs delete Node Dynamicaly

Tags: javascript, vis.js

```
   function addEdgeMode(nodeId){
     network.addEdgeMode();
   }
```

/**need method like network.addEdgeMode(); to delete node 
example: network.deleteNodeMode()*/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not too familiar with vis but according to the [offical vis.js docs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html), I think you can use the [deleteSelected()](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html?keywords=deleteSelected) method like this:

```
function deleteEdgeMode(nodeId){
    network.deleteSelected();
}
```

Also, according to the method description, do note that you do not need to go into editEdge mode or enable manipulation for the `deleteSelected()` method to work.